# How can I get/set a value in a nested object when the key 'is.a.string'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, key

I am working in an angular app where I am being passed an object and a string in dot notation. For example:

```
$scope.obj = {
    x: 1,
    y: 'a',
    z: {
      eks: 1,
      why: 'a',
      zee: 'orange you glad i didn\'t say banana'
    }
  };
$scope.key = 'z.zee'
```

I wanted to be able to get the key's value from the object. Since the key is a string I had to build a function

```
$scope.getValue = function (object, expression) {
    return $parse(expression)(this, object);
};
```

The function gets the value, but now I need to be able to set obj.z.zee to be something else, but I can't do

```
$scope.getValue($scope.obj, "z.zee.punchLine") = 'something else';
```

or

```
$scope.val = $scope.getValue($scope.obj, "z.zee.punchLine");
$scope.val = 'something else';
```

The first one is an error, and the second will only change val.

I tried to create a function that didn't rely on angular's parse but it didn't help either

```
function getValue(object, expression) {
    var expresionList = expression.split('.');
    var value = object;
    for(var index = 0; index < expresionList.length; index++) {
        value = value[expresionList[index]];
    }
    return value
}
```

Is there a way to write back to the object when the dot path of the object is a string?

Here is a **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y4Renj?p=preview)** and snippet to play with.

```js
angular.module('SimpleApp', [])
  // Attribute Isolated Scope
  .controller('simpleCtrl', function($scope, $parse) {
    $scope.testCtrlScope = 'test controller scope';
    $scope.obj = {
      x: 1,
      y: 'a',
      z: {
        eks: 1,
        why: 'a',
        zee: {
          punchLine: 'orange you glad i didn\'t say banana'
        }
      }
    };
    $scope.getValue = function(object, expression) {
      return $parse(expression)(this, object);
    };
    //alt get value
    //   $scope.getValue = function (object, expression) {
    //     var expresionList = expression.split('.');
    //     var value = object;
    //     for(var index = 0; index < expresionList.length; index++) {
    //         value = value[expresionList[index]];
    //     }
    //     return value;
    // };
    $scope.val = $scope.getValue($scope.obj, "z.zee.punchLine");
    console.log($scope.val, $scope.getValue($scope.obj, "z.zee.punchLine"));
    $scope.val = 'something';
    console.log($scope.val, $scope.getValue($scope.obj, "z.zee.punchLine"));
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="SimpleApp">
  <div ng-controller="simpleCtrl">
    {{testCtrlScope}}
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: doldt's answer worked. Here is how I made it work in angular

```
$scope.setValue = function(object, expression, value) {
    var firstPart = expression.substr(0, expression.lastIndexOf('.'));
    var obj;
    var setterKey;
    if (firstPart) {
      setterKey = expression.substr(expression.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
      obj = $parse(firstPart)(this, object);
    } else {
      obj = object;
      setterKey = expression;
    }
    obj[setterKey] = value;
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I advise against doing this `*`, here's a solution:

```
var data = { 
        a:{
          b:{
           c:'hello'
          }
        }
    }

var path = 'a.b.c';
var parts = path.split('.');
var result = parts.reduce(function(soFar,element){
     return soFar[element];
},data);
```

This will put "hello" in the result variable.

Edit: **Assigning values:**
If this referenced value is an object, you can assign to the reference you extract this way. Otherwise (with value types) it's even more of a hassle, you have to stop this loop before the last iteration, and access the reference as the value property of the penultimate object.

`*` *Why I advise against it: this path representation will become a nightmare to work with on the long run, the special semantics of it creates tight coupling in your app, ie. everyone who works with this code has to have knowledge of how this string is parsed.*

Comment: Other than syntax is this different from the alternate solution I have at the bottom of the question?

Comment: On second glance, it does not seem different from that, no. But yours seems to work too, for example `getValue({a:{b:{c:'hello'}}},'a.b.c')` outputs 'hello'. In what cases did this logic produce erroneous output?

Comment: (If the problems were with assigning to primitive values, see my bold edit to my post: if you're dealing with simple value types, you have to stop your  loop a step early to get a reference to the value, and not just the value of it)